# String longer then 2 characters, yet string[1] returns error?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a little python script working which will parse a file I have and return only lines that I want. The code below returns to me an error "IndexError: string index out of range".

```
source = open("source.txt", "r")
new = open("new.txt", "a")
newLine = ""
for line in source:
    newLine = line
    if newLine[1] == "W":
        print newLine
        new.write(newLine)
```

This confuses me because I'm sure that there are more then 2 characters in each of these strings. However if I replace:

```
if newLine[1] == "W":
```

with:

```
if newLine[0] == "[":
```

the code begins to work?

The only problem is that I need to sort by the second character because the first returns an amount of unwanted lines in addition to the ones I want.

Comment: can you log the line in your file and paste it here.

Comment: If Python thinks the line only has one character, and you think it has two, I know which way I'm betting. :-)  Add `print len(line), repr(line)` immediately inside your `for line in source:` loop and find the misbehaving line.

Comment: I bet you have empty lines and didn't think about them.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement of

> I'm sure that there are more then 2 characters in each of these
>   strings

is in exact contradiction with the python exception that the range is out of bounds. In this case, I am likely to trust the computer here. Your test above doesn't work because `if newLine[0] == "[":` is checking the 0th position, whereas your original code is checking the 1st position.

My speculation (impossible to know without seeing your input file), is that you have a newline `\n` somewhere in your file (perhaps the last line), and that is breaking your script.

Comment: if the `\n` is at the last line how would you know it was there by seeing it?